# Built Automation for Electron app in Windows 10, OSX seems to have Permissions problems with it

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, electron

Built automation using Selenium Webdriver for an electron app using chrome 87. Got everything running and generating reports on windows 10, and tried to run the same automation on osx. Started getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/var/folders/3f/3d9220td3b57wf72nbnfxkhc0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.9Yq402/data.json.tmp-31653333844170b6'
at openSync (fs.js:466:3)
at func (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1812)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:33:27)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
at attempt (/Applications/ArbitraryElectronApplication.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/atomically/dist/utils/retryify.js:39:36)
```

I've looked at giving Visual Studio Full Disk Access through the OSX Security and Privacy Settings page, but still getting the same result.

Tried on M1 iMac and Intel Macbook Pro with same results, so it's not the M1 thing.

Comment: In my experience, "operation not permitted" is usually a hallmark of SIP denying you access to an object on disk. [Try using `ls -lO` to inspect whether a file or directory in question is "restricted" meaning it is protected by SIP](https://superuser.com/questions/1049689/which-folders-are-affected-by-system-integrity-protection#comment1475193_1051216), or temporarily disable SIP and see if the operation succeeds then.

Comment: You, or the application, does not have access to that folder. Note that /var is a symlink  to /private/var. It might be worth adding /private/var to Security & Privacy > Privacy - Files and Folders. Personally I'd relocate that directory you're using to /tmp and avoid the issue completely.